# Navigate through records with unbounded fields

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I am trying to navigate through records (next and prev) in a form that i have created in Microsoft Access 2013. The database is connected to SQL Server 2008. First i have loaded the database for the table using SQL:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim Rs As DAO.Recordset
Set dbs = CurrentDb()

strSQL = " SELECT [dbo_tblRank].* " & _
     " FROM [dbo_tblRank] "

Set Rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

Me.rankNo.Value = Rs![rankNo]
Me.rankName.Value = Rs![rankName]
Me.rankDescription.Value = Rs![rankDescription]
Me.noOfRequiredDivings.Value = Rs![noOfRequiredDivings]

End Sub
```

Now i have created a 'next' button, which i would like to update the following fields to the next values. I have written the code (which doesn't do anything):

```
Private Sub btnNext_Click()

Me.Recordset.MoveNext

End Sub
```

What Am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the form is unbound. As a result of this, you've had to write more code in form_open than would have been required were the form/controls bound; Similarly then, in btnNext_Click, you will again have to write more code.

Re-create the recordset, find the current record in the recordset, then move to the next record, and then re-populate your unbound controls from the new record in this new recordset.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be for you to make you recordset public so that you don't have to reconnect each time.
You will still have to write code to find the current record so that you can move pass it in your btnNext_Click event.

The easy way would be to bound your Form...